# How to check if user has access to make post into chatter group?

Tags: chatter, public-group, chatter-groups, collaborationgroup, private

How to check by Apex code if user has access to make post into chatter group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User can post to group in several cases.
Either group is public then any user can post or user has View All Data or Modify All Data permission or user is member of the private group. Otherwise user doesn't have access and chatter post try will result in Insufficient Access level exception.

The code is

```
public static Boolean checkIfUserHasAccessToGroup( Id userId, Id groupId ) {
    CollaborationGroup group = [ Select Id, CollaborationType from CollaborationGroup WHERE Id = :groupId  ];

    if ( group.CollaborationType == 'Public' )  {
        // everyone has access
        return true;
    } else {
        List<PermissionSetAssignment> psaList = [ SELECT Id, PermissionSetId
        FROM PermissionSetAssignment
        WHERE AssigneeId = :userId
        AND ( PermissionSet.PermissionsModifyAllData=true OR PermissionSet.PermissionsViewAllData=true ) ];
        if ( psaList.size() > 0 ) {
        // user has modify all data or view all data permission
            return true;
        } else {
            List<CollaborationGroupMember> cgmList = [ select Id, MemberId, Member.Name, CollaborationGroupId, CollaborationGroup.Name from CollaborationGroupMember where CollaborationGroupId = :groupId  AND MemberId = :userId ];
            if ( cgmList.size() > 0 ) {
            // user is member of group
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        }
    }
}
```